# Pyspark/Python : Converting csv file which has Multiline rows file to single line row file

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a csv file which has records are in multiline like this

```
id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,id6,id7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7

1,2,3,4

,5,6,

7

1,2

3,4

,5,6,


7
```

I want to change the file like below -

```
id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,id6,id7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

I know pyspark can read such file with multiline :True option but I want to convert this file to single line rows which is the business use case. How can I do it. Technologies to be used are either Pyspark or Python (Pandas). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you have something like this in mind?

```
import re

items  = re.findall("[^ ,\n]+", """id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,id6,id7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7

1,2,3,4

,5,6,

7

1,2

3,4

,5,6,


7""")

rows = [items[i:i+7] for i in range(0,len(items),7)]
pd.DataFrame(rows[1:], columns=rows[0])
```

Output:

```
  id1 id2 id3 id4 id5 id6 id7
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

Since it has been requested here is a no loop version of the 2nd part:

```
rows = np.array(items).reshape(len(items)//7,7)
pd.DataFrame(rows[1:], columns=rows[0])
```

I have tested if it actually saves time by using jupter's `%%timeit`: it turns out:

- the regular expression part takes 6.66 µs ± 43.8 ns,
- the old loop part of then turning it into a dataframe takes 759 µs ± 2.81 µs
- and the new numpy version of the same takes 149 µs ± 4.82 µs

Comment: Can there be a better solution which use no loop and column names. I have like 156 columns and its a large file of 1 M records. Doing this for that file would be difficult. This is just a sample data file I gave.

Comment: will you be having strings with doubles quotes in the records as well ?

Comment: @Codegator I have replaced the loop like you requested. I do not understand why you would not want to tell pandas what the column names are. That should not significantly improve performance.